# Contacts - Sending to multiple recipients

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-contacts

Never had to deal with this in the past, but now I have been asked to add a second recipient email on a contact form made with com_contacts.

At first glance this seems to not be supported by the com_contacts. 
So I am wondering if is there any trick that would allow me to add a BCC recipient on that form and finish this task quickly, without having to setup a new form using another component.

Any ideas?

Comment: As I see you really cannot do that with Joomla core contacts component.

Comment: The only thing I see on this that there is a plugin event you could act upon with a `contact` plugin and it is `onSubmitContact`. It is triggered in the controller of com_contacts.

Comment: Yes I though that a plugin could do something like that - but in that case it would be faster to just recreate the form with a forms component. I was hoping that there could be something that I am missing - like a hidden setting somewhere that I am not aware, that would allow this. Thanks @Zollie for taking the time to respond.